# VBA - Unhide row based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I cant find issues in the below code, but it doesn't work, so there have to be any. The code should work like:

1. If D18 = "No" then unhide row 20
2. If D18 = anything else then hide row 20

The code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change2(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Rng1 As Range

With Worksheets("Dashboard")

Set Rng1 = ("D18")

If Rng1.Value = "No" Then Sheet.Rows("20:20").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else: Sheet.Rows("20:20").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

End With

End Sub
```

It does nothing, could you help to find the issue, please?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many issue here

- `Worksheet_Change2` is not a worksheet event
- pointless With block
- `Set Rng1 = ("D18")` invalid syntax
- case sensitive test
- invalid rows reference
- invalid `Sheet` reference
- code runs on all changes

Your code, refactored

Make sure you put it in the code behind the required sheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D18")) Is Nothing Then
       If LCase(Me.Range("D18").Value = "no" Then
           Me.Rows(20).EntireRow.Hidden = False
       Else
           Me.Rows(20).EntireRow.Hidden = True
       End If
   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Your assignment to the range-variable is invalid (it even doesn't compile), and the syntax of your If-statement is invalid also.

```
With Worksheets("Dashboard")
    Set Rng1 = .Range("D18")

    If Rng1.Value = "No" Then
        .Rows("20:20").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Sheet.Rows("20:20").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
end with
```

However, I would condense the code to

```
With Worksheets("Dashboard")
    Set Rng1 = .Range("D18")
    .Rows("20:20").EntireRow.Hidden = (Rng1.Value <> "No")
End With
```

And I wonder about the name of your subroutine. It looks like the copy of an Event-Routine (the event-routine would be `Worksheet_Change` without trailing `2`). When do you want the routine to be called? If you want to have it executed every time it something is changed in the worksheet, get rid of this extra `2` - but in that case you are probably only interested in the case that cell `D18` is changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("D18")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
     With Worksheets("Dashboard")
        .Rows("20:20").EntireRow.Hidden = (Target.Value <> "No")
    end with
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The sub name should be Worksheet_Change to trigger the change event. The sub can be rewritten as follows

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Dim Rng1 As Range
Set Target= Range("D18")
With Worksheets("Dashboard")
    If Target.Value = "No" Then
        .Rows("20:20").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        .Rows("20:20").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End With

End sub
```

Since you are using with worksheets("Dashboard") you can rewrite the sheet.rows as .rows.